# Visual Studio Static Linking for Standalone Exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exe, static-linking

I've read multiple posts with regards to this topic, but none of them have enabled me to build a statically linked exe.

In my **release** configuration (x64) I have the following:

`Configuration Properties -> General : Use of MFC - Use MFC in a Static Library`

`Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation : Runtime Library - Multi-threaded (/MT)`

`Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Command Line : Additional Options - I have all the required Windows libs "kernel32.lib", etc. (as use of MFC removed them from the "All Options" window above)`

`Configuration Properties -> Manifest Tool -> Input and Output : Embed Manifest - No`

Note that in `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input` there are 5 lib files that I'm using in my project, eg `glfw3.lib` and I'm using Full optimisation (/Ox).

After building the project and running the exe myself I receive errors **"The code execution cannot proceed because glfw3.dll was not found..."** etc.

Using dependencywalker I can see that it needs the dlls associated with the libs, which it of course cannot find.

Am I misunderstanding how to do this or is there something else that might be wrong?

(I'm using Visual Studio 2017)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it appears you have a slight misunderstanding.

If something is offered as a DLL, then it is meant to be used as a DLL.  There may be some way to incorporate a DLL into an executable, but it would be a hack.  That's not how things are supposed to work.

The lib file that you are linking against exists simply in order to provide you with functions that you can link against, and these do nothing but delegate to the corresponding functions in the dynamically loaded DLL.  Without it you would have to locate each entrypoint of the DLL yourself, which would be perfectly doable, but a bit cumbersome.

So: you must either find a version of glfw3 which is packaged as a statically linkable library (I have no idea whether one exists) or live with the fact that your .exe will need to be shipped together with glfw3.dll.

Comment: How would I know if the third party libraries used are static linkable; dynamic use lib files and dlls, what about static ones?

Comment: Generally, this information should be provided by the vendor of the library.  But as a rule of thumb, if there are two .lib files, one small, one large, then the large one is for static linking.  If there is only one .lib file, and it is much smaller than the .dll file, then it is for dynamic linking.