# python37.dll not linked in executable

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, visual-studio, dll

I extended c++ with python but the exectuable won't run on systems that do not have python installed.

```
#include "C:\.....python.h"

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print("hello world")\n")
Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

When I run on a windows system without python installed I receive the following error:

```
The code execution cannot proceed because python37.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix the problem.
```

How do I link python37.dll to the executable.

Comment: See [static linking vs dynamic linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993390/static-linking-vs-dynamic-linking). You are linking dynamically; in order to do what you need, you need to statically link the python library (for Windows, this means using `.lib`, not `.dll`).

Comment: I've included the python libraries. (python37.lib) in "library directories" under VC++ Directories.

Comment: I'm not a Windows person, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426047/visual-studio-static-linking-for-standalone-exe) can help? VS has a ton of options, and apparently not all `.lib` files are the same.

Comment: Your program is missing a part it needs for execution. What actually is your question? The error is clear, the remedy seems obvious but you don't ask a question.

Comment: How do I link python37.dll to the executable. Ulrich Eckhardt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A DLL is by definition a dynamically linked library, it is a separate module that is looked up and resolved at run time.

If Python is not installed, your application won't run.

You need to either bundle Python with your application or install Python before/during your application installation.

Alternatively you can try linking with Python [statically](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildStatically), in which case it will become part of the executable and won't need to be installed separately.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your python folder is in your PATH so it can find the DLL in question.

From the command line:

```
c:\> set PATH=c:\python\python37;%PATH%
c:\> cd /d c:\path\to\your\exe
c:\path\to\you\exe> myprogram.exe
```

For more details about how DLLs are found and loaded read the [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order page on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: So basically if the user's windows system does not have python3.7 installed it won't run?